# a question about integration by parts

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

Suppose that $t f(t) \to 0$ when $t \to \infty$ and $t f(t)\to 0$ when $t \to 0$.

For the following integral,

$$I(z)=\int_0^{\infty} f(t) \cos (z t) \mathrm{d}t,\qquad z>0 \tag{1}$$

We can apply the integration by parts and obtain:

$$I(z)=(1/z)\int_0^{\infty} f(t) \mathrm{d}\sin (z t)=-(1/z)\int_0^{\infty}\sin (z t)f'(t)\mathrm{d}t\tag{2}$$

Suppose that we have another integral ($\phi(z) \in \mathbb{R}$):

$$J(z,\phi(z))=\int_0^{\infty} f(t) \cos \left(\mathrm{e}^{i \phi(z)} z t \right) \mathrm{d}t,\qquad z>0 \tag{3}$$

Can we also apply the integration by parts and obtain the following result?

$$J(z,\phi(z))=(1/z)\mathrm{e}^{-i \phi(z)}\int_0^{\infty} f(t) \mathrm{d}\sin \left(\mathrm{e}^{i \phi(z)} z t \right)=$$
$$-(1/z)\mathrm{e}^{-i \phi(z)}\int_0^{\infty}\sin \left(\mathrm{e}^{i \phi(z)} z t \right)f'(t)\mathrm{d}t\tag{4}$$

Comment: You can do that.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Thanks a lot for the answer!